# Is it possible to handle robotframework from anaconda spyder IDE?

Tags: python, anaconda, robotframework, spyder, anaconda3

I have already installed packages through spyder console window.

`pip install robotframework` 
`pip install robotframework-seleniumlibrary`

Please check following code.

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation     Simple example using SeleniumLibrary.
Library           SeleniumLibrary
*** Variables ***
${browser}  chrome
${url}  https://www.google.com

*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    Open Browser     ${url}    ${browser}
```

[Robot file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YG6W.png)

1. When i was run the file using following command `robot TC1.robot` It's shows error.

```
robot TC1.robot
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_21986/637454750.py", line 1
    robot TC1.robot
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[Click on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAUAk.png)

2. Is there any way to use intellibot plugin in spyder IDE so that I can use
   recommendation in robot file.

Comment: Try using relative path while running robot file.robot command

Comment: Maybe you need to add the `!` symbol to run the command as a system shell command. So something like: `!robot TC1.robot`. Also, be sure to set the working directory so the Console can find the file or use the full path to the file

Comment: Hello @DanielAlthviz,

**Is there any way to use intellibot plugin in spyder IDE so that I can use recommendation in robot file.**

Comment: I'm not totally sure. To support completions Spyder uses the Language Server Protocol so if you find a LSP implementation for the robot framework and you are able to manually launch a server instance I think you could connect it to Spyder using the `Completion and linting` preferences: `Tools > Preferences > Completion and linting > Other languages`. If the language is not available there maybe you could submit an issue requesting adding the option at the Spyder issue tracker on GitHub